# Make a generic method for multiple components using service

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a multiple method for sorting different tables:

```
sortFruits(sort: Sort) {
    const direction = sort.direction === 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc';
    this.data.fruits= orderBy(this.data.fruits, [sort.active], [direction]);
  }

sortFamily(sort: Sort) {
    const direction = sort.direction === 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc';
    this.data.family= orderBy(this.data.family, [sort.active], [direction]);
  }
```

I tried to do a generic method on a service:

```
sortTable(sort: Sort, data: any) {
    const direction = sort.direction === 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc';
    return orderBy(data, [sort.active], [direction]);
    // return data;
  }
```

And directly call this service on the view component:

```
 <table matSort (matSortChange)="matSort.sortTable($event, data.fruits)">
```

But the sort doesn't work :-/, what did I do wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: You don't assign your sorting result.

Comment: I tried  data = orderBy(data, [sort.active], [direction]);
But I the view, how I can assign the correct value (example data.fruits) with the correct data sorted ?

Comment: Ok It work, I was missing the reassignment of the variable in the view:
  
    ```
    <table matSort (matSortChange)="data.fruits = matSort.sortTable($event, data.fruits)">

Answer (score 0):

Ok It works, I was missing the reassignment of the variable in the view:

```
<table matSort (matSortChange)="data.fruits = matSort.sortTable($event, data.fruits)">
```

And return the data value on the service

```
sortTable(sort: Sort, data: any) {
    const direction = sort.direction === 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc';
    data = orderBy(data, [sort.active], [direction]);
    return data;
  }
```

Thank's :-)